It is not possible to make a graph of the conversion function of the parameters of two-pole electrical circuits

I'm trying to make such a graph, I don't understand what the problem is, I seem to be doing everything right, but there is a gap in functions. Please tell me, what's the problem?
I tried to change the parameters, somehow eliminate the gap, but my function does not look at all like what is shown in the picture. I don't understand electronics myself, but I need to write a program.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk

def u_(e0, r0, t1, t2, u1, u2):
    num = (u2 / u1 - 1)
    den = np.exp((t1 - t2) / (t1 * u1 / (e0 * r0 * (1 - u1)) - t2)) - 1
    rx_cx = (t1 - t2) / np.log(num / den)
    rx = e0 * r0 * u2 / (t1 * (1 - np.exp((t1 - t2) / rx_cx)))
    cx = rx_cx / rx
    return rx, cx

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("График преобразования параметров двухполюсных электрических цепей")
win.geometry("1000x500")
e0 = 1  # Начальное напряжение
r0 = 1.0  # Начальное сопротивление
t1 = 1.5  # Время 1
t2 = 0.5  # Время 2
# rx = -0.1
# cx = -13
u1 = 0.6
u2 = 0.8
# u1 = e0*rx/r0*(1-np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u1
# u2 = e0*rx/r0*(np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u2

#cx - емкость конденсатора
# rx - сопротивление источника

# Решение системы уравнений относительно rx и cx
rx, cx = u_(e0, r0, t1, t2, u1, u2)
# u1 = e0*rx/r0*(1-np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u1
# u2 = e0*rx/r0*(np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u2
print(f"u1 = {u1:.4f}")
print(f"u2 = {u2:.4f}")
t1_ = np.linspace(t2, t1, 1000)
rx, cx = u_(e0, r0, t1, t2, u1, u2)
# print(f"rx = {rx:.4f}")
# print(f"cx = {cx:.4f}")
u_1 = e0 * rx / r0 * (1-np.exp(-t1_ / (rx * cx)))
# rx = -0.1
# u1 = e0*rx/r0*(1-np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u1
# u2 = e0*rx/r0*(np.exp(-1))  # Напряжение u2
# print(f"rx = {rx:.4f}")
# print(f"cx = {cx:.4f}")
t1, t2 = 3, 1.5
rx, cx = u_(e0, r0, t1, t2, u1, u2)
t2_ = np.linspace(3, 1.5, 1000)
u_2 = e0 * rx / r0 * (np.exp(-t2_ / (rx * cx)))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=80)
plt.plot(t1_, u_1)
plt.plot(t2_, u_2)
plt.xlabel('Время (с)')
plt.ylabel('Напряжение (В)')
plt.title('График преобразования параметров двухполюсных электрических цепей')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# win.mainloop()


What do you mean with "there is a gap in functions"? The graph shows you an initial ramp up, then one signal period at the start, then "dot dot dot" notation implying "the rest of the signal goes here", and then one more period at the end to confirm to the reader that the "dot dot dot" region is the same stable, infinitely repeating signal. If it's about your code, remember to show what it does so in this specific case because you're trying to match a picture: show your own picture too.
